# Выборка данных в mysql

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица `date, time, id, ip`. Необходимо сделать выборку:

1. Определить все значения ip с данным id
2. Найти все id с такими же ip
   **3. Выбрать совпадения IP по дням (интересуют IP в рамках одних интернет-сессий)**

Иными словами, имеется идентификатор пользователя и надо установить, какие еще пользователи выходили с таким же IP-адресом. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить запрос. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Что вы уже пытались сделать?

Comment: Спасибо! А подскажите, как ограничить результат, чтобы показывало только совпадения в рамках одной интернет-сессии ? Например, показывало бы только +\- 1 час совпадения

Comment: @Yuri Задавайте новые вопросы отдельно, а не в виде комментариев к предыдущим.